# Iframe Not displaying anything

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have the following iframe of the example.com domain... The domain does not have a iframe block yet there is no iframe apearing. anyone have any ideas? This code was working before:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe src="//example.com” height="200" width="300"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

**Sorry It was a simple quote issue here is it fixed:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe src="//example.com" height="200" width="300"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

**I thought it may have to do with the //example.com or they updated with a iframe block like stackoverflow and google**
Somewhere like this is what I thought:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe src="//stackoverflow.com" height="200" width="300"></iframe>
<iframe src="//google.com" height="200" width="300"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!—-This is a simple " issue after example.com—->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe src="//example.com" height="200" width="300"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```